# How can I add a numerical value in ComboBox items and display the calculated value in a TextBox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How can I add a numerical value on every item in the ComboBox and display the calculated value to a TextBox in VB.NET?

I tried using this code:

```
Dim value As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 
    Me.combobox1.Items.Add("Single")
    Me.combobox1.Items.Add("Double")
End sub

Private Sub Roomtype_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    If combobox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        value = Val(1000)
    ElseIf combobox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        value = Val(2000)
End sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    txtTotal.Text = Val(value) * Val(textbox1.Text)
End sub
```

For example, I choose the item "single" then multiply its value by 2, I expect the output in the `txtTotal.text` to be 2000 but there's no output.

Comment: Did you debug the code? Are you getting correct values in `value` ?  Is `Button1_Click` code is executing?

Comment: You have two problems with your `Roomtype_SelectedIndexChanged` event handler: 1) _Unless you subscribe to it somewhere using the `AddHandler` statement_, it's missing a `Handles` clause (which should look like `Handles YourComboBoxName.SelectedIndexChanged`). 2) The `If` statement is missing an `End If`, although I think it's not really missing in your real code, otherwise it wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Furthermore, none of the `Val` calls is necessary. They're all redundant, except for `Val(textbox1.Text)`, which should actually be replaced with [`Integer.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse).

Comment: What you should do is create objects with two property values, add them to a list and then bind that to the `ComboBox`.  You can then display one set of property values and access the other property value for the `SelectedItem` via the `SelectedValue` property.  The second property value would be the number by which you multiply the input to get the final output.  Look into data-binding in relation to a `ComboBox` control.